# How to use set cmd in perl call and retrieve the same.

Tags: perl

```
system("set a=10");
system("echo %a%");
system("echo %a%|test.exe"); #it passes a vale to test.exe
```

I am expecting previously set item to be passed to my exe.

Answer (score 4):

That isn't going to work. Each `system()` starts a new process, so while the first process can set an environment variable, it will be lost when the process exits, so the next process that is started by the next `system()` will not see it. Child processes cannot affect the environment of their parents.

**EDITED**

Maybe this will help you achieve what you want...

```
#!/bin/perl
$ENV{"a"}="freddy frog";
print `set b=99 & set`;
```

Output:

```
a=freddy frog
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
b=99 
CLIENTNAME=Console
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=WINXP
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
LOGONSERVER=\\WINXP
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
OS=Windows_NT
```

Comment: Thank u for yours valuable comment

Comment: can we achieve similar to below cmd ;still i am not getting expected value from perl script but in batch file i can system("(set a=10) & echo %a%");